# Mysql group by that counts have different logic

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I have a table with three fields:.

```
field1 - field2 - field3
```

> field1 is a id;
>    field2 is the date;
>    field3 only has two possible
>   values ("ac" and "re").

I need to know if is possible to have a query with `group by` that will give me the results shown at the end:

```
select field2
       , count(total per date)
       , Count(where field3 = "re") 
  from myTable
 group by 1;
```

If my table is:

```
field1 - field2 - field3
=========================
 item1 - date1  - "ac"
 item2 - date1  - "re"
 item3 - date1  - "re"
 item4 - date2  - "re"
 item5 - date2  - "ac"
 item6 - date3  - "ac"
```

The result will be like:

```
 - date1 - 3 - 2
 - date2 - 2 - 1
 - date3 - 1 - 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT field2, COUNT(*), SUM(CASE WHEN field3='re' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as re_count
FROM table1
GROUP BY field2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional `sum` with  the `case` statement:

```
select field2
     , count(field3)
     , sum(case when field3 = 're' then 1 else 0 end)
from myTable
group by field2
```

or even shorter, using `if`:

```
select field2
     , count(field3)
     , sum(if(field3 = 're', 1, 0))
from myTable
group by field2
```

or just:

```
select field2
     , count(field3)
     , sum(field3 = 're')
from myTable
group by field2
```